# how to get date after 2 days from the given time in php

Tags: php, datetime

i want to find out the date after days from the given time.
for example. we have date 29 may 2015
and i want to cqlculate the date after 2 days of 25 may 2015
$Timestamp = 1432857600 (unix time of  29-05-2015)

i  have tried to do it with following code but it is not working
  $TotalTimeStamp = strtotime('2 days', $TimeStamp);

Answer (score 2):

Missed the `+` - `strtotime('2 days', $TimeStamp);` .
Add the `+` to `+ 2 days`.

Use `date` & `strtotime` for this - You can try this -

```
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime(' + 2 day', strtotime('2015-05-16')));
```

`$Timestamp` & `$TimeStamp` are not same(may be typo). For your code -

```
$Timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$TotalTimeStamp = strtotime('+ 2 days', $Timestamp);
echo date('d-m-Y', $TotalTimeStamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Php does have a pretty OOP Api to deal with date and time.

This will create a \DateTime instance using as reference the 25 May 2015 and then you can call the modify method on that instance to add 2 days.

```
$date = new \DateTime('2015-05-25');

$date->modify('+2 day');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

You may find this resource useful:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dates-and-time-the-oop-way--net-35395

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add seconds to your timestamp if you have a timestamp ready:

```
$NewDateStamp = $Timestamp + (60*60*24 * 2);
```

In the above, sec * min * hours = day -- or 86400 seconds. * 2 = 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5 you can also use D

```
  <?php
   $date = date_create('2015-05-16');
   date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('2 days'));
   echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
  ?>
```

OR

```
   <?php
     $date = new DateTime('2015-05-16');
     $date->add(new DateInterval('2 days'));
     echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
    ?>
```